# pyspark losing milliseconds converting strings to timestamps with custom format

Tags: pyspark

Not sure if this is a bug, but I'm having trouble converting a string to a timestamp while preserving the milliseconds part with a custom format.

When I was experimenting with a ISO-8601 formatted string, explicitly providing a format causes the parser to drop the millisecond portion of the timestamp.

Am I wrong in that a capital `S` is the incorrect symbol for milliseconds for the SimpleDateFormat format?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp

data = [['2018-07-20 15:11:22.023']]
schema = StructType([
    StructField('datetime_string', StringType(), nullable=False)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

df2 = df.withColumn('timestamp', to_timestamp(col('datetime_string')))
print(df2.first().timestamp.microsecond) # 23000, as expected

df3 = df.withColumn('timestamp', to_timestamp(col('datetime_string'), format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'))
print(df3.first().timestamp.microsecond) # 0, unexpected!
```

Environment information:

- Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)
- pyspark v2.3.0 (Also reproducible on 2.3.1) Installed via conda
- Output of "java -version", installed via "apt-get install openjdk-8-jre"

  openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: It looks like openjdk problem. did you try it with oracle java?

Comment: Just tried using Oracle java and got the same results (verified by checking SparkUI's environment tab at http://localhost:4040/environment/). I read somewhere that Spark's TimestampType actually does not support sub-second resolutions. That's a bummer cause I'm working on IoT sensor data operating at 10hz.